# Getting firebase error when trying to upload to storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm getting the next error in console when trying to upload to firebase:

```
Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: Invalid argument in `put` at index 0: Expected Blob or File.
```

js:

```
var file, fileName, fileRef, storageImagesRef, storageRef, uploadTask;
var storageFolder = '/pictures/';

function getFileName(fileInput) {
file = fileInput.files;
fileName = file[0].name;
storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(storageFolder + fileName);
uploadTask = storageRef.put(file);

};
```

html

```
<input type="file" onchange="getFileName(this)" accept=".png, .jpg, .bmp, .JPEG, .JPG, .svg, .tiff, .gif">
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is due to the way the `file` variable is used in your code. The variable is assigned the `FileList` - which is what you are passing to `put`. It would be less confusing if you assigned it the `File`:

```
function getFileName(fileInput) {

    file = fileInput.files[0];
    fileName = file.name;
    storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(storageFolder + fileName);
    uploadTask = storageRef.put(file);
};
```

Comment: Worked like a charm Thanks a lot!

Comment: No worries. You should consider accepting the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers